# D-Bus linking issue

Tags: linker-errors, dbus, pkg-config

I have been trying to compile a program for `dbus` and as suggested I did in the code as mention to a similar question. I did execute it as shown:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags dbus-glib-1` \
  `pkg-config --cflags dbus-1` \
  `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` \
   dbus-example.c \
  `pkg-config --libs dbus-glib-1` \
  `pkg-config --libs dbus-1` \
  `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

I am still getting the following error:

```
Package dbus-glib-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `dbus-glib-1.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'dbus-glib-1' found
Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glib-2.0' found
Package dbus-glib-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `dbus-glib-1.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'dbus-glib-1' found
Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

I installed the above mentioned packages, but still the error persists.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you installed the development packages for those libraries, or just the libraries themselves? On Debian/Ubuntu, you want `libdbus-glib-1-dev` and similar `-dev` packages for the others; on Fedora, you want `dbus-glib-devel` and similar.

Comment: I'm curious about how you knew to install these packages. This solved my problem on Fedora, but I had no idea this package existed. Where should I have looked? thanks

Comment: On Fedora you can check what provides a pkg-config package by running `dnf provides 'pkgconfig(dbus-glib-1)'` or just directly install whatever provides it with `dnf install 'pkgconfig(dbus-glib-1)'`.

Comment: `dnf search dbus-glib` would also have helped. I knew to install these packages after a decade of developing software using these libraries!